# "John's" or "of John" in this context

Tags: grammar, pronouns, spoken-english

In the sentences below:

> All the mistakes are **mine.**

Likewise,

> All the mistakes are **John's.**

Now,

Can we say:

> All the mistakes are **of me**.

And

> All the mistakes are **of John.**

Are these sentences correct?

Which are fine in spoken English?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  You could say, "All the mistakes were made by me" or "All the mistakes were made by John".  (I prefer "all the mistakes are mine".) . But you can't say "All the mistakes are of me" or "These are/were mistakes of me".  Try googling "the mistakes are of me"; only 1 hit.  "the mistakes are mine", hundreds of thousands of hits.